# Permalinks issue with Wordpress in subfolder and domain redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-redirect

I installed a Wordpress website on an hosting space where there was already an active website. I didn't want to delete that so I put Wordpress in its own directory, having: http://domain.com/wordpress

In the `wp-config.php` file I set:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://domain.com/wordpress/');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://domain.com/wordpress/');
```

Then, I created an `.htaccess` file in the root and one in the wordpress folder. They respectively contain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress [L]
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This way, when I go to http://domain.com/ I get redirected to http://domain.com/wordpress and everything on the website works fine. What I want, though, is to have the url displaying just http://domain.com, without the "wordpress" part. Is something I can achieve just with the `.htaccess`?

Another issue I'm facing is that there is a redirect domain set. There is this `http://otherdomain.com` pointing to http://domain.com. This other domain should actually be the main one. Right now, when I access http://otherdomain.com the website is displayed correctly; the links are working, but the url doesn't change accordingly: it always shows http://otherdomain.com, no matter what.

What I tried so far is to search and replace all the entries in the database, substituting the domains and modify other options accordingly. Doing this the website is shown without css, no images and no links working.

Answer (score 1):

To fix issue with subfolder try to replace

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

with

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress/index.php
```

Don't forget to replace yourdomain.com with exact domain name.

Also, please revert database changes back, as right now WordPress is trying to find files in the root dir.

If this won't work, you might have such redirect option in your hosting account panel.

Comment: no, this didn't work. this way not even the links to pages or posts worked anymore

Comment: have you reverted database changes back?